# java pattern regular expression matching

Tags: java, regex

I'm really bad with pattern matching.  I'm trying to take in a password and just check that it meets this criteria:

- contains at least 1 lowercase letter
- contains at least 1 uppercase letter
- contains at least 1 number
- contains at least one of these special chars:    @#$%
- has a minimum length of 8 characters
- has a maximum length of 10 characters

**This is what I have:**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,10})");
```

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(in);

```
if(!matcher.find())
{
  return false;
}
else
{
  return true;
}
```

**I would also like to do something like this:**

```
int MIN = 8,
MAX = 10;

"((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{MIN,MAX})"
```

but I get some weird message about malformed expression.

Something isn't right.  My program crashes with this.  I don't know what's wrong.  Any ideas?

```
   private boolean isValidPassword(String in)
{
    /*          PASSWORD MUST:
    *   contains at least 1 lowercase letter
    *   contains at least 1 uppercase letter
    *   contains at least 1 number
    *   contains at least one of these special chars: @#$%
    *   has a minimum length of 8 characters
    *   has a maximum length of 10 characters
    */

    Pattern hasLowercase = Pattern.compile(".*[a-z].*");
    Pattern hasUppercase = Pattern.compile(".*[A-Z].*");
    Pattern hasNumber    = Pattern.compile(".*[0-9].*");
    Pattern hasSpecial   = Pattern.compile(".*(@|#|$|%).*");

    Matcher matcher = hasLowercase.matcher(in);

    if (!matcher.matches())  //a-z
    {
        return false;
    }

    matcher = hasUppercase.matcher(in);

    if (!matcher.matches())  //A-Z
    {
        return false;
    }

    matcher = hasNumber.matcher(in);

    if (!matcher.matches())  //0-9
    {
        return false;
    }

    matcher = hasSpecial.matcher(in);

    if (!matcher.matches())  //@#$%
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(in.length() < MIN_LENGTH || in.length() > MAX_LENGTH)   //length must be min-to-max.
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Regular expressions are not the answer to every problem. You can also write the rules as multiple conditions and combine them with &&. This will be easier to understand and modify in the future.

Comment: I need a working pattern matcher.

Comment: Why are you limiting the password length?

Comment: "but I get some weird message about malformed expression" what does the message say? BTW it looks like you have extra `(` at start.

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using `find` but `matches()` since you don't want to check if some part of text can be matched by regex, but if regex matches whole text. Aside from that `if (condition){return true;}else{return false;}` can be simplified to `return condition;`.

Comment: @Poke Particularly when working w/ existing systems there may be hard limits in the DB or API that are impractical to change. Not a great situation to be in, but it happens. When it does I've generally created a new field and relegated the existing weak password length to legacy. ¯\(°_o)/¯

Comment: I saw your edit suggestion - you're not supposed to append your final code to my answer. If you want to show it, you must put it in your **own** post, either as an answer, or as an edit in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this with regular expressions, it would be much easier to test the input against multiple simple expressions rather than one single and excessively complex expression.

Test your input against the following regexes.
If one of them fails, then the input is invalid.

```
.*[a-z].*
.*[A-Z].*
.*[0-9].*
.*(@|#|$|%).*
```

Additionnally, check the length of the input, with basic string methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to help you with crashing without more information, but I do have a suggestion.

Instead of trying to create one giant regex expression, I would recommend making one expression for each rule, then test them all on the string individually.  This allows you to easily edit the individual rules if you decide you want to change/add/remove rules.  This also makes them easier to understand.

There is also the option of not using regex, which would make your rules pretty easy using the string contains method with [these character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)

As for the malformed expression, you should concat the MIN and MAX like this:
`"((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{" + MIN + "," + MAX + "})"` which will insert the values of MAX and MIN into the string.

Comment: Tried, but it still gives malformed.

Comment: I was just commenting on inserting the values of MAX and MIN, I did not run through the actual regex itself.  If you want to debug the regex, I would recommend a site like regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

I think that your expression might be off, but I found one that meets what you are looking for.
`"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,10})"`

You can modify the min and max length by using

`"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{" + MIN + "," + MAX + "})"`

I have included this RegEx in Regexr so you can see how it works.
http://regexr.com/3gnbd

Also, for future reference when testing Regular Expressions, [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) is very helpful for seeing the different components.

You also should use if/then statements to return true or false, because you could just return the tested condition instead. `return matcher.find()` eliminates the need for an if statement.